# What does, "Tighten with specifed torque at curb position of vehicle" mean?

Tags: hyundai, struts, accent, torque-specification

Hyundai service manual for strut assembly reverse installation states: "Tighten with specifed torque at curb position of vehicle"

What is curb position? Is this the same as curb weight?

I was looking into changing out the struts on a 2015 Hyundai Accent and noticed this caution note at the bottom of the procedure.

If this is referring to curb weight, does this mean tighten the bolts, then put the weight of the vehicle on the axle, and then torque to specification? And is this for all bolts (axle mount, and upper mount in engine bay)?

If so, what's the best way to accomplish this without the wheel on?

Also, what is the reason for this? Just to better understand.

Here is a link to the procedure I'm using: [manual](http://www.hamanual.com/replacement-859.html)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 5):

This means that the final torqued setting has to be done with the vehicle sitting on its wheels so the suspension is in the "normal" position. So this can be on the pavement or when on a ramp but the mass of the vehicle must be taken by the wheels.

If you tighten the bolts/nuts with the suspension "hanging down" then the rubber bushes end up "stretched when the suspension takes the mass of the vehicle and stretched even more when the suspension flexes which leads to premature failure.

To avoid confusion for some, the type of ramp I am referring to is shown in the image:
[image]

These are common in some countries and also used for vehicle testing in many establishments. These ramps are installed with the metal surfaces where the wheels go level, which is useful as trying to find  apiece of perfectly level ground can often be a challenge, even a concrete driveway is usually constructed with a slight slope to promote drainage.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you've written, the vehicle should be on level ground when doing this, not on a ramp. If on a ramp, the center of gravity will change, which will change how the bushings/springs are loaded, which will cause undue wear on them during use, which is what you are trying to prevent in the first place.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 There are ramps of many styles, ramps with two metal wide rails **are** suitable, as the wheels take the mass of the vehicle. Ramps which have swinging arms which have pads used on the jacking points are **not** suitable as that means the mass of the vehicle is **not** supported by the wheels...

Comment: Yes, what you are calling "ramps" I'd refer to as a "lift", which works completely fine for what I'm talking about. The vehicle is level, so all is good. And, you're right about a slight incline, which won't make much of a difference. I'm talking about having the front wheels a foot higher than compared to the back wheels, or visa-versa.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The phrase "put it on the ramp" is **so** often used, when post lift, scissor lift etc would be the correct **technical** term...

Comment: The phrase "put it on the ramp" is common *where you are from* ... not from where I'm from. This is local color and semantics, but to me a ramp is a ramp. A lift is a lift.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 a lift is used in buildings...

Comment: Hmmm ... that's an elevator, isn't it? ;-) Wait, is that a bonnet or a hood? A trunk or a boot? I can't remember, lol.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 lots of words in the dictionary :) but as long as the OP gets the idea we have done it right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I replaced struts on a Chevy Cobalt in the past I used a Haynes manual, and I do recall it mentioning to torque the top strut mount nuts in the engine bay once the wheels were on the ground, which makes sense because of the rubber mount at the top. But I'm confused about the lower mount to the axle. Does this need to be tightened with the car weight as well?

Comment: I'm with Mike on this one. The thing in the picture is a 4-post lift, but commonly referred to as a ramp... The thing in a building is definitely a lift, except if it's not for people, in which case it's a freight elevator.

Comment: @eaglei22 Yes, because of how the bush "sets" when the fixing is tightened.

Comment: @SolarMike which bushing? The one at the top of the strut?

Comment: @eaglei22 you asked about the lower mount in your comment.

Comment: Interesting word differences. I'd suggest staying away from the words with different meanings. "Tighten the lugs with the vehicle level, and the wheels holding the vehicle's weight."

Comment: I'm not aware of a bushing at the lower mount. But if there isn't one, it shouldn't make a difference if I torque the lower mount then set the vehicle on the ground and let the upper bushing/grommet compress and then torque the top correct? I'm doing this in my house garage, so I don't have access to a ramp you demonstrated in your answer. I will be using a floor jack and jack stands. So if I can torque the lower mount (if there are no bushings) before putting the weight of the car on the strut that would be easier and safer for me.